# How to include the pass down state 'Test = Down' of previous product till the state of the product is back to 'Production = UP' using PL SQL

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have this data where I need to include the pass down state of previous product whenever it is in state 'Test' = DOWN for certain Product and stop when it is in state 'Production' = UP for the same product. For PRODUCT_STATE, whenever there is one 'DOWN', the PRODUCT_STATE will be 'DOWN".

Current table example:

[image: Current table example]

Expected results:

[image: Expected results]

Comment: Please include create table scripts, dml scripts and the expected output. I deleted my posted answer because I misunderstood the question.